# Apache rewrite rule regex

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule to redirect files in my new webhelp system (it's a stand alone website).
I have two things I try to take into account - 
I want to redirect only files that are in the http://www.mydomain.com/webhelp folder.
I need to change the .html in the end to .htm...
I manage to find each rule by itself by matching the http://www.mydomain.com/webhelp, but 
when I try the rewrite cond it breaks...

Basically, its
http://www.mydomain.com/webhelp/hello.html
into
http://www.mydomain.com/webhelp/hello.htm
without changing
http://www.mydomain.com/index.html

Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backreferences. Something like:

```
RewriteRule   ^www/webhelp/(.*)[.]html([#])(.*)[.]html$ www/webhelp/$1.htm$2$3.htm
RewriteRule   ^www/webhelp/(.*)[.]html$ www/webhelp/$1.htm
```

Comment: Hi Gillyspy, thanks for the help. It dosn't work, I think it because it seems the URLs could be a bit more complicated, like this: http://www.mydomain.com/webhelp/webframe.html#advanced_improv.html

Comment: meaning you would need to rewrite both `.html` into `.htm` ? How many could there be?  What about two rules as i've rewritten above?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following in a `.htaccess` file in your `webhelp` folder, it should achieve what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /webhelp/
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this is a more polished version of the exact same thing.  If you don't mind please edit existing posts to polish instead of posting new answers or add comments.

Comment: yes thanks for your comment, you are correct. I'll try this now and let you know. Thanks for the time :)